# ValueError: Layer sequential_2 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a simple Model using the IAM Handwritten dataset from Kaggle and some sample code from a textbook I'm using, but I keep getting an error when I try to fit the model.

The error says `ValueError: Layer sequential_2 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]`

full source code :

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
from random import *
from PIL import Image
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Lambda, ELU, Activation, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, Cropping2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, RMSprop

d = {}
from subprocess import check_output
with open('./forms_for_parsing.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line.split(' ')[0]
        writer = line.split(' ')[1]
        d[key] = writer
print(len(d.keys()))

tmp = []
target_list = []

path_to_files = os.path.join('./input/data_subset/data_subset', '*')
for filename in sorted(glob.glob(path_to_files)):
#     print(filename)
    tmp.append(filename)
    image_name = filename.split('/')[-1]
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(image_name)
    parts = file.split('-')
    p = parts[0].split('\\')
    form = p[1] + '-' + parts[1]
    for key in d:
        if key == form:
            target_list.append(str(d[form]))

# print(d)
# print(parts[0])
# p = parts[0].split('\\')
# print(p[1])
# print(form)
img_files = np.asarray(tmp)
img_targets = np.asarray(target_list)
print(img_files.shape)
print(img_targets.shape)

for filename in img_files[:20]:
    img=mpimg.imread(filename)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(img, cmap ='gray')

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(img_targets)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(img_targets)

print(img_files[:5], img_targets[:5], encoded_Y[:5])
train_files, rem_files, train_targets, rem_targets = train_test_split(
        img_files, encoded_Y, train_size=0.66, random_state=52, shuffle= True)

validation_files, test_files, validation_targets, test_targets = train_test_split(
        rem_files, rem_targets, train_size=0.5, random_state=22, shuffle=True)

print(train_files.shape, validation_files.shape, test_files.shape)
print(train_targets.shape, validation_targets.shape, test_targets.shape)
batch_size  = 16 # 8
num_classes = 50

# Start with train generator shared in the class and add image augmentations
def generate_data(samples, target_files,  batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.1 ):
    num_samples = len(samples)
    from sklearn.utils import shuffle
    while 1: # Loop forever so the generator never terminates
        for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
            batch_samples = samples[offset:offset+batch_size]
            batch_targets = target_files[offset:offset+batch_size]

            images = []
            targets = []
            for i in range(len(batch_samples)):
                batch_sample = batch_samples[i]
                batch_target = batch_targets[i]
                im = Image.open(batch_sample)
                cur_width = im.size[0]
                cur_height = im.size[1]

                # print(cur_width, cur_height)
                height_fac = 113 / cur_height

                new_width = int(cur_width * height_fac)
                size = new_width, 113

                imresize = im.resize((size), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Resize so height = 113 while keeping aspect ratio
                now_width = imresize.size[0]
                now_height = imresize.size[1]
                # Generate crops of size 113x113 from this resized image and keep random 10% of crops

                avail_x_points = list(range(0, now_width - 113 ))# total x start points are from 0 to width -113

                # Pick random x%
                pick_num = int(len(avail_x_points)*factor)

                # Now pick
                random_startx = sample(avail_x_points,  pick_num)

                for start in random_startx:
                    imcrop = imresize.crop((start, 0, start+113, 113))
                    images.append(np.asarray(imcrop))
                    targets.append(batch_target)

            # trim image to only see section with road
            X_train = np.array(images)
            y_train = np.array(targets)

            #reshape X_train for feeding in later
            X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 113, 113, 1)
            #convert to float and normalize
            X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
            X_train /= 255

            #One hot encode y
            y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
            yield shuffle(X_train, y_train)
train_generator = generate_data(train_files, train_targets, batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.3)
validation_generator = generate_data(validation_files, validation_targets, batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.3)
test_generator = generate_data(test_files, test_targets, batch_size=batch_size, factor = 0.1)
def resize_image(image):
    return tf.image.resize(image,[56,56])

# Function to resize image to 64x64
row, col, ch = 113, 113, 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(row, col, ch)))

# Resise data within the neural network
model.add(Lambda(resize_image))  #resize images to allow for easy computation

# CNN model - Building the model suggested in paper

model.add(Convolution2D(filters= 32, kernel_size =(5,5), strides= (2,2), padding='same', name='conv1')) #96
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2), name='pool1'))

model.add(Convolution2D(filters= 64, kernel_size =(3,3), strides= (1,1), padding='same', name='conv2'))  #256
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2), name='pool2'))

model.add(Convolution2D(filters= 128, kernel_size =(3,3), strides= (1,1), padding='same', name='conv3'))  #256
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2), name='pool3'))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(512, name='dense1'))  #1024
# model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(256, name='dense2'))  #1024
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_classes,name='output'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))  #softmax since output is within 50 classes

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
nb_epoch = 8

samples_per_epoch = 3268
nb_val_samples = 842

# #save every model using Keras checkpoint
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
#filepath="check-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}.hdf5"
filepath="low_loss.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath= filepath, verbose=1, save_best_only=False)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

# #Model fit generator
history_object = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = (samples_per_epoch/batch_size),
                                      validation_data=validation_generator,
                                      validation_steps=nb_val_samples, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

and this is error i got :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-99c01bc062d8> in <module>
     12 
     13 # #Model fit generator
---> 14 history_object = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = (samples_per_epoch/batch_size),
     15                                       validation_data=validation_generator,
     16                                       validation_steps=nb_val_samples, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks_list)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    322               'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    323               instructions)
--> 324       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    325     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(
    326         func, new_func, 'deprecated',

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1813     """
   1814     _keras_api_gauge.get_cell('fit_generator').set(True)
-> 1815     return self.fit(
   1816         generator,
   1817         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    812       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    813       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 814       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    815       if self._created_variables:
    816         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2826     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   2827     with self._lock:
-> 2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3208           and self.input_signature is None
   3209           and call_context_key in self._function_cache.missed):
-> 3210         return self._define_function_with_shape_relaxation(args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _define_function_with_shape_relaxation(self, args, kwargs)
   3139           expand_composites=True)
   3140 
-> 3141     graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
   3142         args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)
   3143     self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3063     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3064     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3065         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3066             self._name,
   3067             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:975 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
    C:\Users\subha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:155 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Layer ' + layer_name + ' expects ' +

    ValueError: Layer sequential_2 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

i couldn't understand the error message so kindly somebody help me out!

thank u

Comment: I have the same problem. did you solve it?

Comment: no @mohamed_18 even 'm still looking for help.